# VB.net rearrange string data from 20171019 to 19/10/2017

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone assist me with learning how to rearrange data from a format of (example) `20171019` to `19/10/2017`?

The `20171019` is obtained from a SQL query as a string, the data type being `nvarchar(255)`, but I then want to display it as a standard date format.

Do I somehow assign each character of the string a position (value) and then rearrange those values, or is there a formatting tool built within VB?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Why you obtain a `DateTime` as string from your database? Why you don't store it as `DateTime` or `Date`?

Answer (score 3):

On clientside you have to parse the string to `DateTime`, then you can use `ToString(format)` to apply a specific format. But the important question is why you need that,  why you get a `DateTime` as string from your database? Why you don't store it as `DateTime` or `Date`?

However, here is how you parse and convert:

```
Dim dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20171019", "yyyyMMdd", Nothing)
Dim result = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy replies. Unfortunately, the databases are from a third party tool so we are stuck with their design, hence the need to modify. Thanks again, i'll give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with RegEx:

```
Dim dt as String = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("20171019", "^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})", "$3/$2/$1")
```